# simple Filesystem

Tags: filesystems

I wanna implement a very, very simple filesystem. I just came across the following resource
and I am wondering if maybe someone tried to do the same and could point me out where
it is best to start for me.

Many thanks

http://web.archive.org/web/20091027130707/http://geocities.com/ravikiran_uvs/articles/rkfs.html

Answer (score 6):

You could look at [FUSE - Filesystem in Userspace](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). It is a system that makes filesystem development much easier than normal filesystem development inside the Kernel. For example the [hellofs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html) is a small, extremely limited filesystem in less than 100 lines of C code.

I designed a [small series of homeworks for students](http://pc2.uni-paderborn.de/teaching/lectures/speichersysteme/) to development an really simple filesystem using FUSE. Unfortunatelly, the resources for the course are currently only available in German. The filesystem used is based on the book ["UNIX Filesystems"](http://books.google.com/books?id=zj9E4_6zsHgC&dq=UNIX+Filesystems&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=uEm6bcaEJb&sig=RbcRpDk1c0aEzC0qQZkR0x6yRaE&hl=en&ei=PLVlSsKRKNSi_Abgm_VR&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1) by Steve Pate - A pretty good resource on filesystem development.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants FUSE.

Answer (score 2):

Try and look at some of the first, non-journaling filesystems on Minix or Linux. You should be able to find something to look at by browsing their legacy code.

Also pick up a book like Modern Operating Systems by Tanenbaum. This contains some low-level theory. If you want to write the driver for Linux then there is a [free book](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) on writing drivers/fs modules for Linux

Good Luck

Comment: When I checked the last time, "Linux Device Drivers" had no chapter on filesystems. However, for all other concerns about Kernel development the book is really good.

Answer (score 1):

FAT (specifically FAT16) is an *extremely* simple filesystem -- so simple in fact that building a FAT16 filesystem driver was a single programming lab assignment for a 200-level Computer Science course when I was in school.

If you want to get an idea of the minimum complexity necessary for a real-world filesystem, that's a decent one to look at.